# ShowDialog in Fragment for DateTimePickerDialog

Tags: java, android

I am trying to follow along this tutorial: http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/01/using-timepickerdialog-and.html

However, showDialog cannot be resolved because I am using a fragment. How can I use a DateTime Picker Dialog inside of a class that extends a fragment?

Thanks.

EDIT: Show code:

```
 @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
            {
                        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                        setContentView(R.layout.date_and_time_picker);

                        // get the references of buttons
                        btnSelectDate=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonSelectDate);
                        btnSelectTime=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonSelectTime);

                        // Set ClickListener on btnSelectDate 
                        btnSelectDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                // Show the DatePickerDialog
                                 showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
                            }
                        });

                        // Set ClickListener on btnSelectTime
                        btnSelectTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                // Show the TimePickerDialog
                                 showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID); //not resolved in fragment
                            }
                        });

            }
```

Comment: have u able to open the fragment in android

Comment: Provide the code and explain the problem

Comment: @HarshParikh, updated to show. When I use showDialog() in fragment, it is not resolved.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me in a fragment

```
Time currDate = new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());
currDate.setToNow();
DatePickerDialog d = new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener, 
                     currDate.year,  currDate.month, currDate.monthDay);
d.show();
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener = 
                     new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() 
{
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear, int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) 
    {
         // Do as you need
    }
};
```

Comment: Put this code in a method inside your fragment and call that method

Comment: I'm confused how do I replace show Dialog from the method in here:  btnSelectDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Show the DatePickerDialog
                showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
            }
        });

Comment: Post your complete Fragment class